# Integer Arrays Passing To JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array in php which i am getting in Javascript. 
Here is my php code

```
$query = "SELECT SeatNum FROM `$busNum` WHERE AB = 1";
$runQuery = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$i = 0;
foreach($runQuery as $row)
{
    $availableSeats[$i++] = $row['SeatNum'];
}
```

And here i am getting this string in javascript

```
var getBookedSeats = <?php echo json_encode($availableSeats); ?>;
var bookedSeats =[];
for(var i =0 ; i <getBookedSeats.length ; i++){
 bookedSeats[i] = getBookedSeats[i];
}
```

The array also saved in bookedSeats successfully. Now the problem is that when i used that array as a parameter to call function. Nothing goes in the parameter. Even there is no problem of scope. This is my function looks like:

```
 var init = function (reservedSeat) {
//code
}
init(bookedSeats);
```

Implementation of init function is :

```
   var settings = {
            rows: 5,
            cols: 15,
            rowCssPrefix: 'row-',
            colCssPrefix: 'col-',
            seatWidth: 35,
            seatHeight: 35,
            seatCss: 'seat',
            selectedSeatCss: 'selectedSeat',
            selectingSeatCss: 'selectingSeat'
        };

        var init = function (reservedSeat) {
            var str = [], seatNo, className;
            for (i = 0; i < settings.rows; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < settings.cols; j++) {
                    seatNo = (i + j * settings.rows + 1);
                    className = settings.seatCss + ' ' + settings.rowCssPrefix + i.toString() + ' ' + settings.colCssPrefix + j.toString();
                    if ($.isArray(reservedSeat) && $.inArray(seatNo, reservedSeat) != -1) {
                        className += ' ' + settings.selectedSeatCss;
                    }
                    str.push('<li class="' + className + '"' +
                              'style="top:' + (i * settings.seatHeight).toString() + 'px;left:' + (j * settings.seatWidth).toString() + 'px">' +
                              '<a title="' + seatNo + '">' + seatNo + '</a>' +
                              '</li>');
                }
            }
            $('#place').html(str.join(''));
        };
```

Comment: when you view the page source on the rendered page, what does `var getBookedSeats = <?php echo json_encode($availableSeats); ?>;` actually look like? Also there is an easier way to copy an array.

Comment: @epascarello it is like: ["1","2","4","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70","71","72"];

Comment: are you calling init() before your variable bookedSeats is being set?

Comment: @JoshKG i tested this by using alert function and i am not calling init() function before. i think the problem is that integers are saved in array as string variables, but i need them as integers.

Comment: Oh so this is not a problem of the bookedSeats being undefined, but a problem of your init function expecting something different than you're giving it. Please show the full definition of init().

Comment: if the problem is that you have the numbers as strings, you can use bookedSeats = bookedSeats.map(Number)

Comment: @JoshKG i have posted the code in question. Kindly watch it.

Comment: Does look like you're searching for a number (seatNo) inside an array of strings. No match will be found in that case.

Comment: @juvian Map function works dude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem is that you are trying to compare the array values as numbers and you currently have them as strings. To convert them to numbers, you can simply use:

```
bookedSeats = bookedSeats.map(Number) // iterate over each bookedSeats element and return its numeric value
```

Which is the same as:

```
bookedSeats = bookedSeats.map(function(value){
    return Number(value);
})
```

Comment: Array.prototype.map is indeed an elegant way to change the type of your array values, but keep in mind it is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and below.

Comment: You can also do it in PHP: `json_encode(array_map('intval', $availableSeats));`. That will work in older IE versions.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it looks like your variable bookedSeats is being assigned with values. However, if your init() function is expecting integers, you'll want to build the bookedSeats array with integers like so:

```
for(var i =0 ; i <getBookedSeats.length ; i++){
 bookedSeats[i] = parseInt( getBookedSeats[i], 10 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not use php but I belive php's json_encode returns a JSON formatted string. Which results in your JavaScript code storing individual characters from the string into the bookSeats variable.

You need to parse the string returned from php. For example...

```
var getBookedSeats = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($availableSeats); ?>);
```